# Tensorflow example seems broken, function returns different graph depending on mode. How can this work?

Tags: tensorflow

Reading through the tensorflow tutorials, specifically https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers, there is a function that does something to the effect of:

```
def some_model(mode):
    # some stuff here
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions)
    # some other stuff here

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(
            loss=loss,
            global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)
 # return something else dependent on condition
```

The above does not make sense to me in that if you build the model with mode set to predict, does it not initialize the weights from scratch/some initializer meaning that the results at this step are purely arbitrary? 
if so why do this? 
surely you should return a model suitable for training that can predict as well as train?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model function only to provide a graph tailored to the specific usage required (i.e., the `mode` you pass).

The idea behind this function is that you plug in your graph only what is necessary for the specific mode:

- Prediction: You only need your model (from input to `predictions` output).
- Evaluation: On top of what provided by prediction, you need some kind of accuracy measures to evaluate on.
- Training: On top of what is provided by Prediction, you need to compute the loss, attach an optimizer and get a train operation.

In all of this, the part of the graph you actually learn on (i.e., your network's weights) is *always the same*, because it is always contained between your input and output tensors. The variables in that graph section are loaded from a checkpoint file, if available, or reinitialized otherwise.

The other nodes attached to the graph are what actually changes between different operation modes, but none of those nodes is necessary outside their specific phase (e.g., once you're done with training, you can dispose of loss computation, optimizer and all the boilerplate needed around it).

Comment: In the tensorflow tutorial example I linked above the function to generate graphs does not load from a checkpoint, returning a build, untrainable model if the mode is set to "PREDICT", I guess they did this simply to show it was possible? isn't that rather pointless? Regardless thank you for taking the time to reply.

Comment: I think they show that part to explain what's the prediction setup. Once the model is trained, rerunning that part **should** load from the checkpoint.

Comment: I actually went away and tested this and can confirm this is the case. When reloading a graph from a checkpoint you must construct an identical graph and the correct parts are loaded based on tensorflow scopes.